# How to duplicate matrix in theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

Hi I am new to theano and I need [N x M * 4] dot [M x P], so I want second matrix to be duplicated 4 times.

Something like

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.fmatrix("x")

z = x.repeat(3, axis=0)

foo = theano.function([x], z)

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]).astype("float32")

c = foo(a)

print c

[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
```

But in my case I want

```
[[ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.]]
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You want [`theano.tensor.tile`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.tile):

```
z2 = T.tile(x, (3, 1))  # repeat 3x in the first dimension, 1x in the second
bar = theano.function([x], z2)

print(bar(a))
# [[ 1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.]
#  [ 1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.]
#  [ 1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.]]
```